# Getting request Authorization header in ZF2 controller

Tags: http, zend-framework, curl, zend-framework2

I am using ZF2 and for some reason, I can get all the headers I send EXCEPT the Authorization header - it's like its filtered out.

I am trying to get all the headers in the controller like this:

```
    public function createAction($data) 
    {
        $request  = $this->request;
        print_r ($request->getHeaders());
        exit();

    }
```

I send the request through cURL like this:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: test" -H "Authorization: 123456" -H "Content-Type: qwerty" -X POST http://localhost/test
```

All headers prints out EXCEPT authorization header. I can add any arbitrary header and it prints it out - just no the 'Authorization' header...

I've also tried to get()/has() for the authorization header, yet it does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer here:

http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/HTTP-Digest-authentication-does-not-work-with-PHP-as-CGi-td4658790.html

Had to add the following to the projects .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Works fine for me (ZF2 Version 2.1.4):

`curl -i -H "Accept: test" -H "Authorization: 123456" -X POST http://zf2.localhost`

Results in:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2013 09:44:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.7
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-ch
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 843
Content-Type: text/html

object(Zend\Http\Headers)#168 (3) {
  ["pluginClassLoader":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["headersKeys":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "useragent"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "host"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "accept"
    [3]=>
    string(13) "authorization"
  }
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(10) "User-Agent"
      ["line"]=>
      string(23) "User-Agent: curl/7.26.0"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "Host"
      ["line"]=>
      string(24) "Host: zf2.localhost"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Accept"
      ["line"]=>
      string(12) "Accept: test"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "Authorization"
      ["line"]=>
      string(21) "Authorization: 123456"
    }
  }
}
```

With the following code:

```
$request  = $this->getRequest();
var_dump($request->getHeaders());
```

Use the following to get the value:

```
$authVal = $request->getHeaders('authorization')->getFieldValue();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It does not work for me. I tried on a colleagues machine in his project, and there it works, but not on mine. What on earth could be causing this specific header not to be parsed?!

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you in zf2

```
  $headers = $request->getHeaders();
  $authorization = $headers->get('Authorization')->getFieldValue();
```

$request is object of `Zend\Http\Request`;