# How to send headers for testing APIs

Tags: rest, zend-framework2, phpunit

I have a ZF2 application and when implementing my API I decided to go with token authentication for every request. Everything works fine, except I can't write my UnitTests because I can't seem to set headers for Authorization:

In my PHPUnit Test Case:

```
// Option 1
$_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Authorization:Bearer asdfghjkl';
$this->dispatch('/api/v1.0/someResource');

// Option 2
headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers;
$header = $headers->addHeader()->fromString("Authorization:Bearer asdfghjkl");
$this->getRequest()->setHeaders($header);
$this->dispatch('/api/v1.0/someResource');
```

Then in my EventManager I try:

```
$request = $e->getRequest();
$headers = $request->getHeaders();
var_dump($headers);
```

Or:

```
$headers->has("Authorization")
```

Both show no sign of my Authorization header...

So how do I set the header for testing http header authentication with tokens?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945231/getting-request-authorization-header-in-zf2-controller

Comment: @HaimEvgi the solution posted there is in case you use php as a cgi and not as an apache module. I am running as a module, and even following the suggestion, didn't fix the issue.